# Best practices for managing state and props in larger React apps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, reactn

I would like to understand more about the best practices for passing props around parents-child in react. the problem comes from having a standard way of doing this in a medium-large project to minimize confusion and technical debts such as performance optimization. So far, I only knew these methods on doing this:

1. standard prop drilling

```
Pros: easy
Cons: will become unmanageable in complex feature
```

2. utilizing React.Context

```
Pros: medium difficulty, naturally separate from main component
Cons: more time to write, may be unnecessary for smaller components, will do re renders that will cause performance issues headaches in, for example, large forms.
```

3. using global state from 'reactn' module

```
Pros: easy
Cons: will get unmanageable for large projects that have tons of components, cannot prevent rerender AFAIK.
```

4. using Redux

```
Pros: robust and compatible with firebase (react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore), can prevent rerender using areStatesEqual,
Cons: more boilerplates, more work to do for simpler state management
```

is there a guideline on standard practices on doing this? what do you people use for medium-larger projects? thanks!

Comment: If your app needs to optimized, then do go for `redux` as it does optimization from the start. Otherwise, in most cases, `context` would do just fine. On a side note, do consider [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) as well (personal fav) as it does caching, asynchronous data-handling and updating out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the reccomendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The following answer is subjective!`

There are basically 3 categories that I am aware of.

1. Keep everything local ( For any size of app which doesn't deal with sibling dependencies this will work fine. May cause some prop drilling, though it should be avoided as possible, it's not an anti-pattern. You come with better approaches to handle this i.e. `PureComponent`, `React.memo`, `shouldComponentUpdate`)
2. Keep everything global(`redux`/`reactN`/`...`) (have not seen this approach in my experience, not recommended in my opinion as requires you to hit central state every time when there is a change)
3. Keep a mix of both. (Highly seen this in medium to large scale projects, we use this approach with redux)

#### Choosing an option:

1. Personally speaking, irrespective of the size of an application one can start with the first approach and add the central state later when required(if you are not sure where to put states).
2. If you need to manage some state centrally from the beginning it can be added from start(if states are clearly defined).

If you choose any one of the above two approaches, to begin with, at one point in time you would need to decide either go for first-party i.e. `React Context` or a third party i.e. `Redux, ...`.

You have already stated the pros and cons of these, you can compare and see which one outweighs the others.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple answer from the list you provided I would suggest redux, writing actions and reducers does add a certain amount of overhead, and as react evolved and matured it now seems you can manage large applications w/o the use of redux: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367. But once you get how redux works you will be able to scale with ease. This is a good solution for react-redux beginner-intermediate level devs.

The best suggestion I have for you is to use react only.
useContext and useReducer will get you very far, but it requires an intermediate - experienced development skills. This approach will force you to invest time in data-structure, encapsulation of components and use of advance react patterns. (I would enroll to something like https://kentcdodds.com/workshops/advanced-react-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your references to `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore`, I am assuming that you are using Firestore.

I prefer using a Context for most of my mid-to-large size apps with Firestore. (This is your option #2). However, as you point out, there is a bit of drudgery in setting up and managing the context, so I ended up writing my own state management library for Firestore in React apps.

You might want to check out [@gmcfall/react-firebase-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gmcfall/react-firebase-state)
. It removes most of the drudgery.  Moreover, it is resilient in the face of multiple mount/unmount cycles that may occur when [Concurrent React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#what-is-concurrent-react) kicks in.