# Best Practice for my case: Callback/Drill Down or useContext?

Tags: reactjs

I'm still learning React JS and have just a general question that I want to know whether it is recommended to use drill-down and callback functions or useContext (or anything else) if I want to transfer data from component A to B (and obviously vice versa). In my actual case, I would also use more components that are nested.
I think, declaring everything that will be needed in both components inside App.js does not make much sense if there are lots of declarations and there is probably a better approach to this.

Simplified example:

```
  function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <A />
      <B />
    </>
  );
}

const A = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>A</h1>
      <input value=""></input>
    </>
  );
};

const B = () => {
  const changeTextfieldInA = () => {
    // change the value in the input of A to "X"
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>B</h1>
      <button onClick={() => changeTextfieldInA}>Change text</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for managing state and props in larger React apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716529/best-practices-for-managing-state-and-props-in-larger-react-apps)

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple case props and callbacks are the best solution. You're right that it can get messy when the app gets bigger. But the need for another solution (Redux...) generally does not come before long. Props and callback are fine !

Comment: In the end, the case will be that 99% of the components will be communicating with one single component. So wouldn't that mean that if there were for example 15 components talking to the same component, that this specific component would be too complex/complicated with x different parameters, etc?

Comment: If you really have 15 sibling components, then first of all you should ask yourself, do I really need 15 siblings components... There are very few cases where it is absolutely needed, most of the times you'll have at most 3 or 4 siblings. Plus, the parent component will only store the states and pass the props & callbacks. It won't look that ugly. But if you really need lots of sibling components with sophisticated state management in the parent, then sure, go for Redux or any other state management tool. I still guarantee you it'll be overkill tho